# Embedding `org-id`s into their headers when exporting to HTML

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I have need to export `org-mode` files to html for a wiki like system. I am making use of `org-protocol` so that I can act on links in html files with `emacsclient`, usually to open an org buffer at point based on its `org-id` (I am using uuids).

I would like to streamline this process so that these links are automatically embedded into its respective header, such that I can simply click on a header while viewing the html file. I have had some success using kitchen's guide [here](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2018/05/09/Making-it-easier-to-extend-the-export-of-org-mode-links-with-generic-functions/) in converting existing org-mode links to the protocol syntax on export, but not in extracting the `:ID:` property of a header and creating a link in the header.

Comment: Hi! Can you share some code that you tried to extract the ID?

Comment: Hmmm I can't seem to edit my question to include the code block